# inserting multiple items with total number of each item

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve to store multiple item[]  which have specific total amount and to store them all.
example:

```
[item]   => Array(
                  [0] => computer
                  [1] => table
                )
[issue_qty]  => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 3
                )
[batch_no] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2003140001
                    [1] => 2003140002
                )
//first I want to get multiple item
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($item); $i++):
    //second I want to insert according to number of issued qty for each item
    for($j=0; $j < sizeof($issue_qty); $j++):
        $data= [
            'item'            => $item[$i],
            'issue_qty'       => $issue_qty[$i],
            'batch_no'        => $batch_no[$i],
        ];
       //insert into database
    endfor;
endfor;
```

It is inserting only some data but not all according to number of issue quantity.
Can someone review my code what I miss to check the condition or if possible to achieve this in better way

Comment: As you don't use the `$j` loop value, have you tried removing this?

Comment: You want multi data or a data with multi items, issue and batch_no?

Comment: Can you show what the 7 rows you are expecting are

Comment: @JuanSebastiánMoreno I want to insert multi item with multi data

Comment: @NigelRen 5 number of computer and  3 number of table to be inserted by this array `$data= [
            'item'            => $item[$i],
            'issue_qty'       => $issue_qty[$i],
            'batch_no'        => $batch_no[$i],
        ];`

Comment: I have solved it

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the code and found that I was checking the size of array which is 4 and it was inserting 4 times not 8 times. So I count the number of insert value in issue_qty in variable count and loop it again, it work!

```
[item]   => Array(
                  [0] => computer
                  [1] => table
                )
[issue_qty]  => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 3
                )
[batch_no] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2003140001
                    [1] => 2003140002
                )
$count=0;
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($item); $i++):
    $count =$issue_qty[$i];
    for($j=0; $j < $count; $j++):
        $data= [
            'item'            => $item[$i],
            'issue_qty'       => $issue_qty[$i],
            'batch_no'        => $batch_no[$i],
        ];
       //insert into database
    endfor;
endfor;
```